# Change fontawesome icon/class when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, font-awesome

I have an icon `<i id="test" class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>`

That when clicked, I'd like to change it's classes in order to become `<i id="test" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>`

So basically remove `fas` and add `far`, or vica versa if clicked again.

https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/ptsgba1h/7/

HTML:

```
<i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
<hr/>

<div>
  <i id="test" class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).toggleClass('fas');
    $(this).toggleClass('far');
  });
});
```

Any ideas why the classes are not being toggled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using awesome version SVG with JavaScript which replaces `<i>` tags (and others) matching a set of criteria with `<svg>`

so , in your case change `data-prefix` attr to be `fas` Or `far`

here is a full example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','#test', function() {
    console.log(this);
    //$(this).data("prefix",$(this).data("prefix")== 'fas' ? 'far' : 'fas')
    $(this).attr("data-prefix", function(index, attr){
      return attr == 'fas' ? 'far' : 'fas';
   })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
<hr/>

<div>
  <i id="test" class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: `delegate()` was deprecated a *long* time ago, you really shouldn't be using it. Use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) instead. Similarly use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data) to retrieve data attributes, not `attr()`

Comment: in this case if you used `.on()` you will see that it logs only once , but `.delegate()` doesn't , and for `attr` i used it because of the callback function and it makes the same behavior at the end

Comment: I agree, the function argument pattern is nice for `attr()` but it's still better to use jQuery's `data` cache for a lot of reasons, not least of all is consistency. Also note that `on()` works properly when you use the correct, delegated signature. Read the docs I linked to. In this example it's `$(document).on('click', '#test, fn)`. Not that event delegation is even needed in this instance.

Comment: you're right for using `.on()` function and i edit the answer for it , but for `.data` it doesn't make the expected result but `attr()` did it

Answer (score 2):

The `<i>` elements are replaced with `svg` elements based on the `fa-*` class when used with `far` / `fas`, and they contain classes of this kind: `svg-inline--fa fa-times-circle fa-w-16`. This is the reason the class toggle code does not work

A better solution would be to show / hide the appropriate icon on click.